# how to access color in recharts from json?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm using barchart in recharts

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, color:'yellow', amt: 2400 },
];

const SimpleBarChart = (data) => ({
  return (
    <BarChart
      width={600}
      height={300} data={data}
      margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
      <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
      <YAxis/>
      <Legend />
      <Bar dataKey="pv" fill={data.color} />
    </BarChart>
  );
})
```

I want to use color from the json. What should be the syntax of fill in the code ?

Comment: Do you import data in the componet or pass it as props?

Comment: @Gh05d as props(updated the code)

Comment: Well, then it should work. Do you get an error?

Comment: @Gh05d i'm getting black color(for all the bars)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the color value that is stored in the first element of your `data` array, you just need to write the following:

```js
<Bar dataKey="pv" fill={data[0].color} />
```

Because `data.color` yields no values, since it does not exist.

Comment: how to access the index in larger data?

Comment: What do you mean in larger data ?

Comment: how to make it dynamic using indices ( data[i].color)

Comment: A bar can have only a single color, what do you want to achieve ? What do you want to have in the end ?  Multicolor bars? One bar per node with a color each?

Answer (score 0):

You can this either by talking to the array directly by doing this;

```
let data = [
  { 
    name: 'Page A', 
    uv: 4000, 
    pv: 2400, 
    color:'yellow', 
    amt: 2400 
  }
];

console.log(data[0].name)

OR 
by looping through the array doing this;

for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  console.log(data[i].name)
}
```